# Why can't our expanding universe be an imploding universe that appears expanding relative to us?

Tags: black-holes, universe, space-expansion

Galaxies moving away from us is our proof of an expanding universe. However, if the universe was contracting towards a black hole we would see a galaxy ahead of us accelerating faster towards that black hole. A galaxy behind us would still be accelerating towards the black hole but slower than we would be. So relative to us both galaxies would be moving away. 
How can we tell which scenario we are in?

Comment: How do you explain this is happening is *every* directions ?

Comment: Also what you're describing may show blueshift for everything instead of red. As for the contracting universe I have wondered how time dilations could affect our perception of the universe. As our Galaxy grew did time slow down locally? Does time moves slower now than it did in the past and does that affect the far away things we are seeing?

Comment: *"if the universe was contracting towards a black hole"* - if there were metric contraction of space rather than metric expansion, the would be no center of contraction just as there is no center of expansion.

Comment: The universe is so unimaginable huge and our field of viewing so tiny, even with huge telescopes, there will never be anything above, below or to the side of us that is in exactly the same position we are. Therefore, whatever we see will always be in front or behind and the resultant velocity will always show a red shift.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we take four galaxies around our galaxy all at the same distance $d$:

[image: Galaxies]

If the whole lot of us were falling towards a black hole the trajectories of the five galaxies would look like this:

[image: Falling galaxies]

So while it's true that the two galaxies ahead of and behind us would be accelerating away, the other two galaxies would be accelerating towards us. So we could tell immediately that we were accelerating towards a point in space. Instead we find that all four galaxies are moving away from us, so we know this can't be the case.

This is an example of a [tidal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force), and it's characteristic of the spacetime geometry around a black hole. It's responsible for the [spaghettification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghettification) of any astronauts unfortunate to fall into a black hole.